# std::system() not working correctly

Tags: c++, shell, command-line, cmd, system

If I execute the command "C:\Windows\system32\java.exe" on the commandline I get information about how to use java as it should be. However, when i write a simple c++ program to do the same

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::system("C:\\Windows\\system32\\java.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following console output:

```
'C:\Windows\system32\java.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am using the mingw-w64 compiler on windows 10.

Comment: Do you have a `java.exe` in `C:\Windows\system32\ `?

Comment: this might sound strange, but have you double checked there's a java.exe in that folder?

Comment: Yes, I have java.exe in `C:\Windows\system32`.

Comment: Try the command `where java.exe` in your command interpreter, to verify.

Comment: The result of "C:\>where java.exe" is
"C:\Windows\System32\java.exe".

Comment: try to begin debug std::system("ls") std::system("dir")  std::system("dir /c") std::system("dir c:") etc ...

Comment: try to recognize internal paths using std library routines like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097

Comment: All these commands work the same way as if I would have entered then directly at the cmd.

Comment: try getcwd from <unistd.h> possible it is not exists on windows http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html but possible, it is possible framework dependent

Comment: Are You use #include <cstdlib> at code it is not exists? my system it is not compiled with iostream, instead cstdlib

Comment: Do you run your program with administrative permissions? By default nothing can get access to Windows directory.

Comment: Seems odd that you'd have java.exe in system32...mine is in C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

Comment: I have l launched the cmd the following way: "Run as administrator". It compiles without <cstdlib>.

Comment: I have tried getcwd which works and the path it returns is the location of the .exe I am running.

Comment: Write please for all, is the answer with "SysWOW64" or any other  was helpfull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is compatibility [redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by Windows on x64 systems:

> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64.

If your console is 64 bit and application built as 32 bit (or vice versa) they'll show content of different system32 directories under same name.

Comment: I have just reinstalled mingw-w64 with the x86_64 architecture instead of the i686 one. Everything works now. Thank you all for your help.